# Create regular expression using android pattern

Tags: android, regex

I have a sample message . I need to create a regular expression to validate  using android pattern.

**sample message :**
ERR|any digit|any digit;

**checking validation:**

1.Starting fixed characters :ERR

2. separator character :|
3. digit after | character
4. Message termination ;

I have tried like this way:^{ERR}+{|}+\d+{|}+\d+{;}$

Am I right? Please help  to solve my problem.

Comment: you should add regex tag to your question you might recieve help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corrected regex you gave would be `^(ERR)+(\\|)+\\d+(\\|)+\\d+;$`. Brackets are used for grouping, not braces. Also, in regex, `+` is used to represent "one or more of the previous expression". So writing `(ERR)+` means "one or more of the string 'ERR'", so strings like "ERRERR|123|456;" would be matched (same thing goes for the pipe characters) - this is not what you are trying to do, I assume.

Having said that, **try this**: `"^ERR\\|\\d+\\|\\d+;$"`

Comment: The elimirks answer is formally correct (based on what we know), only needs some double escaping: ``Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^ERR\\|\\d+\\|\\d+;$");``

Comment: @GsusRecovery Thanks for the correction - I updated it accordingly